# É possível criar domínios com acentos?

Tags: dns

Suponho que não, mas por que não? E temos alguma previsão disso ser aceito algum dia?

Estou torcendo para o [namecoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namecoin) ou [alguma nova moda de DNS](http://b.mtjm.eu/dns-replacement-unnamed.html) pegar logo!

Observação: sei que arrisco [ser marcado como fora de contexto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316383/how-to-create-own-domain-extension).

Comment: é possivel sim aliás olha ai o exemplo [não.net](http://www.xn--no-sia.net/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registros no brasil e alguns internacionais já permitem caracteres especias. [Veja esta notícia do Registro.br de 2005](http://nic.br/imprensa/arquivo/clipping/2005/midia15.htm):

> O serviço de registro de domínios passará a aceitar, a partir de 09/05, caracteres permitidos na língua portuguesa, tais como vogais acentuadas e o cedilha. Com isso, poderão ser cadastrados e acessados sites com endereços como http://www.pãodeaçúcar.com.br.

- [Os que aceitam caracteres especiais](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Internationalized_generic_top-level_domains)
- [Root Zone Database](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db)

Exemplo prático:

- [www.sãopaulo.com.br](http://www.s%C3%A3opaulo.com.br)
- [www.wikipédia.org](http://www.wikip%C3%A9dia.org)

Comment: Olha, bacana! Até hoje não sabia dessa... :) Mas o pão aí não funcionou! :( Tem algum exemplo prático?